# react useEffect async triggering eachother problem how solve you guys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

```
useEffect(()=>{
 // console.log(`Ahanda items`,items)
 setItems(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`baskets`)) )
},[])


useEffect(()=>{ 
    localStorage.setItem(`baskets`,`${JSON.stringify(items)}`)
},[items])
```

Hello i have classic async problem have.
problem is
there is basket for eccommerce shopping site basket simple one i want to
when site is refreshing  if localstorage inside have any list of product item pull
and setItem
but the problem is the other items Useeffect works to. So if i add timeout and do like that :

```
useEffect(()=>{
 // console.log(`Ahanda items`,items)
 setItems(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`baskets`)) )
},[])

useEffect(()=>{ 
  setTimeout(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(`baskets`,`${JSON.stringify(items)}`)
  }, 200);
},[items])
```

but the problem is not solved because some times i can be use api's

here is other explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mTvd1O-3nM

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really hard to understand what your problem is here.

Comment: This line won't work as you expect:  `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`baskets`)) != items`.  Two objects/arrays are not equal unless they are the same object/array, it doesn't matter that their contents are the same, they are not equal.

Comment: @James i editted  my code can you look right know pls ?

Comment: @AKX  i editted my code can you look right know pls ?

Comment: @Foxsnow I see you edited your code, but I'm not following what the problem is you're having. (In any case you're essentially forking your `localStorage`d state to component-local state, which is likely not to be what you want.)

Comment: @AKX i add video can you look at it pls.

Comment: @James i add video can you look at this pls.

Answer (score 0):

I might get the question wrong. But please correct me.
Are you looking for something like this ????

```
const[items, setItems] = useState([])

function handleFetchItems(){
   if(localStorage.baskets){ //call this only if I have items 
    setItems(state =>[...state,...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`baskets`))]  
   }
   fetch(`url`).then((response) => { //async operation
       setItems(state =>[...state,...response])
    }).catch(() => {}) 
}



useEffect(useCallback(() => {handleFetchItems()},[]))
```

Comment: i add video can you look this pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I already face This problem, and solve it by making a custom hook :

[image]

by the way, This custom hook was created by Kent creator of Remix , you can check it here : https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-hooks

**usage:**

```
const [name, setName] = useLocalStorageState({
 defaultValue: 'default value',
 key: 'name',
})
```

- name is the value stored under the key 'name' in localStorage
- setName is the setter of the new data in key 'name' in localStorage